# Parsing structured text data

Tags: text-parsing

I extracted blob field out of mysql table in text format:

```
CAST(orders AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8)
```

Now each field looks like this:

```
a:2:{s:4:"Cart";a:5:{s:4:"cart";a:2:{i:398;a:7:{s:2:"id";s:3:"398";s:4:"name";s:14:"Some product 1";s:5:"price";i:780;s:3:"uid";s:5:"FN-02";s:3:"num";s:1:"1";s:6:"weight";s:1:"0";s:4:"user";s:1:"4";}i:379;a:7:{s:2:"id";s:3:"379";s:4:"name";s:14:"Some product 2";s:5:"price";i:750;s:3:"uid";s:5:"FR-01";s:3:"num";s:1:"1";s:6:"weight";s:1:"0";s:4:"user";s:1:"4";}}s:3:"num";i:2;s:3:"sum";s:7:"1530.00";s:6:"weight";i:160;s:8:"dostavka";s:3:"180";}s:6:"Person";a:17:{s:4:"ouid";s:6:"103-47";s:4:"data";s:10:"1278090513";s:4:"time";s:8:"21:33 pm";s:4:"mail";s:15:"mail@mailer.com";s:11:"name_person";s:8:"John Doe";s:8:"org_name";s:13:"John Doe Inc.";s:7:"org_inn";s:12:"667110804509";s:7:"org_kpp";s:0:"";s:8:"tel_code";s:3:"343";s:8:"tel_name";s:7:"2670039";s:8:"adr_name";s:26:"London, 221b, Baker street";s:14:"dostavka_metod";s:1:"8";s:8:"discount";s:0:"";s:7:"user_id";s:2:"13";s:6:"dos_ot";s:0:"";s:6:"dos_do";s:0:"";s:11:"order_metod";s:1:"1";}}
```

What I can notice is that this text goes in order: `[type]:[length]:[data];`, where `[type]`: **s** stands for **string** and **a** stands for **array** (or dictionary in Python). It also has `i:'number':` groups without `[length]:`.

I don't see better solution than parsing it with regex in several passes, though I don't clearly understand how to parse nested dictionaries (in Python terminology).

**The question:** is it a standard data structure that already has a parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the output from the PHP serialize function (you need to unserialize it):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

If you are working in python, there is a port of the serialize and unserialize functions here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/phpserialize

```
Anatomy of a serialize()'ed value:

String
s:size:value;

Integer
i:value;

Boolean
b:value; (does not store "true" or "false", does store '1' or '0')

Null
N;

Array
a:size:{key definition;value definition;(repeated per element)}

Object
O:strlen(object name):object name:object size:{s:strlen(property name):property name:property definition;(repeated per property)}

String values are always in double quotes
Array keys are always integers or strings
    "null => 'value'" equates to 's:0:"";s:5:"value";',
    "true => 'value'" equates to 'i:1;s:5:"value";',
    "false => 'value'" equates to 'i:0;s:5:"value";',
    "array(whatever the contents) => 'value'" equates to an "illegal offset type" warning because you can't use an
    array as a key; however, if you use a variable containing an array as a key, it will equate to 's:5:"Array";s:5:"value";',
     and
    attempting to use an object as a key will result in the same behavior as using an array will.
```

Comment: Nice! And yes, I'm working with Python, so your link is extremely helpful. Thank you!